# KKT approach to multilevel optimization

Tags: optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

I am looking for a Karush-Kuhn-Tucker transformation to the following three-level optimization problem:

$\displaystyle \max_{x_2}  \frac{\left(x_{1} - x_{3} - 2\right)^{2}}{18 x_{1} - 18 x_{3}} \left(- x_{1} + x_{2}\right) \left(x_{2} - x_{3}\right) \\$

$\displaystyle \textrm{s.t.}\\
\displaystyle \max_{x_1}  \frac{1}{72 \left(x_{1} - x_{3}\right)^{2}} \left(- x_{1} + x_{2}\right) \left(3 x_{1}^{2} + 2 x_{1} x_{2} - 2 x_{1} x_{3} - 2 x_{2} x_{3} + 2 x_{2} - x_{3}^{2} - 2 x_{3}\right)^{2} \\$

$\displaystyle \textrm{s.t.}\\$
$\max_{x_3}  \frac{1}{72(x_{1} - x_{3})^{2}}(- x_{2} + x_{3})(x_{1}^{2} + 2 x_{1} x_{2} + 2 x_{1} x_{3} - 8 x_{1} - 2 x_{2} x_{3} + 2 x_{2} - 3 x_{3}^{2} + 6 x_{3})^{2} $

I am not quite sure how to proceed with it, do you have any tips to offer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not understand the part "s.t. $\max_{x_1} f(x)$". Do you mean that $x_1$ has to maximize $f(x)$?

Comment: Yes, x1 and x3 are lower level variables and has to maximize their respective lower level problems. x2 has to maximize the upper level problem subject to that x2 maximizes the first lower level problem, subject to that x3 maximizes the second lower level problem. Hope it made it clearer!

Comment: I do not think you can easily express those constraints. The inner optimization problems are not convex, so the KKT conditions are not sufficient.

Comment: Ok, thank you! Do you think it is hopeless to try to reformulate the problem as an MPEC with another approach? Might you know of any other methods I could employ in order to solve a problem like this?